# Laravel : to join 2 join OR order with null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, laravel-5

**How do join this:**

```
$query->leftJoin('tbs_111', 'tbs_111.111_id', '=',  'tbs_222.222_id');
$query->where('tbs_111.111_id', null);
$query->select('tbs_222.*');
```

**And this:**

```
$query->join('tbs_111', 'tbs_111.111_id', '=',  'tbs_222.222_id');
$query->orderBy('tbs_111.111_id', $order);
$query->select('tbs_222.*');
```

OR ,  if
        $query->where('tbs_111.fine_id', null);

return any number. Exm 1. And After sort all expression.

```
    $query->leftJoin('tbs_111', 'tbs_111.111_id', '=',  'tbs_222.222_id');
    $query->if('tbs_111.111_id', null)->return('tbs_111.111_id', 1); //fake code
    $query->orderBy('tbs_111.111_id', $order);
    $query->select('tbs_222.*');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finded solution for second part question

```
$query->leftJoin('tbs_111', 'tbs_111.111_id', '=',  'tbs_222.222_id');
$query->orderBy(\DB::raw('IFNULL(tbs_111.111_id , 1) '), $order);
$query->select('tbs_222.*');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query->leftJoin('tbs_111', 'tbs_111.111_id', '=',  'tbs_222.222_id')
      ->where( function($query) use ($order) {
       if(!is_null($order)){
       $query->where('tbs_111.111_id', $order)
       }
       })->select('tbs_222.*');
```

Comment: No...Where is sort? 
What s 
    `$query->where('tbs_111.111_id', $order)`
if $order like 'asc' or 'desc' ?